# Ubuntu to replace Vista and thereby reboot my computer?

Tags: windows-vista, mbr

Ubuntu was recommended to me as a viable option to Vista. I am unable to boot up my computer and have no recovery media. I keep seeing 'BootMGR is missing' on the screen.
If I were to download Ubuntu and then burn it to a disc or discs:

A. Would It have the BootMGR as a part of the program?

B. Could I then go into BIOS and boot up my computer from the disc drive with Ubuntu overwriting Vista thereby reviving my computer?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

BootMGR is easily fixed from a Windows recovery disc. [see this link for an example.](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Vista+Bootloader+from+the+DVD)

If you install Ubuntu (and I do recommend it) it will autodetect Vista and set an option for you to boot into it after it's done installing. It cannot do it from the CD, however. Windows' boot loader needs to be fixed for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu you can tell it to install alongside with the existing operating system this will at least save all your files you have on the other partition. Ubuntu will be able to read and modify all the files you have on the Vista partition.